# Visual Studio Modeling and covariance in generic arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, modeling

I'm using Visual Studio Modeling project and code generation with partial clases.
Some interfaces have generic parameters and generic constraints for these parameters. I'm using Template Parameters to specify the parameters, their types and their constraints.
All code is generated successfully so far.

Now, i want to add a variance and covariance in these generic parameters. Here is the problem:

How i can specify the "in" or "out" tag in generic parameters?

Edit: In addition, i want put generic arguments in Methods too, but Template Parameters not found in method properties toolbox. It's possible specify generic parameters to methods too?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty generic:

```
public interface IFoo<in T, out TResponse>
{
    TResponse DoSomething(T entity);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it "direct write in code". But, i want to auto-generate the code from UML class diagram.

Comment: Sorry missed that piece.

Comment: @OscarJimenez, really, people still do that?!?? UML can be a nice way of generating secondary docs of code/design, but I didn't realise anyone actually tried to generate code *from* UML.

Comment: I think you will need to use a template. Thanks for the -1.

Comment: David, i known, but would be usefull generate a "body-empty" partial clases to force the code to be up-dated from model in Model-Driven approach.
Thanks William, i'm already using a T4 template but i don't re-code a functionality if it was implemented in Visual Studio.